# Protecting Javascript

Tags: node.js

I am learning how to create a Mysql connection with NodeJS and noticed something that concerned me. All of the database access information is present right in the javascript file which can be easily seen by anyone, which is obviously a huge vulnerability.

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'example.org',
  user     : 'bob',
  password : 'secret'
});
```

I modified my .htaccess file to protect the source code from being seen, however it breaks my NodeJS app. Here is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex disabled
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:3000/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1 [P,L]

# Deny access to files with extensions .ini, .psd, .log, .sh, .js
<FilesMatch "\.(ini|psd|log|js|sh)$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# Deny access to filenames starting with dot(.)
<FilesMatch "^\.">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# Hide files of type .png, .zip, .jpg, .gif and .doc from listing
IndexIgnore *.png *.zip *.jpg *.gif *.doc *.js *.php
```

How do you go about securing access information without breaking the NodeJS app?

Comment: Where is this file used? Is it on the server or are you serving it to the browser?

Comment: NodeJS scripts can't be seen client-side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1: Sensible variables**

You have some choices but the rule is:

- Dont store password inside the code (hard coding passwords)

The easier way is:

1. Create environment variables to put the sensible information
2. From Node.js, access to the env vars through process.env.MY_ENV_VAR_FOR_MYSQL_PASSWORD

Also, env vars are a good place to put the variables depending on the environment, for example local development vs production: mysql hostname, user, password, etc

And finally, for really sensible information:

- You can have a "store" on the cloud, example: Azure has key vault and Amazon AWS has KMS. Both support also Hardware protection for critical data.

**Problem 2: Prevent javascript code to be downloaded**

For this scenario, I recommend run Node.js at port, for example, 3000 (doesn't matter but bigger than 1024. Below 1024 needs root privileges)
And put NGinx acting as a proxy, redirecting the request to localhost port 3000. In this way, your JS content will never be sent through port 80.
If you app has static content, you can create your public or assets folder and expose it through the proxy NGinx.

Hope this helps. For regular projects, env vars could be enough. Regards